# Android Studio Java passing data through intents

Tags: java, android

Im having some trouble with this specific intent and i am not too sure why, this is my problem at the moment. Im making a very basic quiz app and when the user completes the quiz and wants to retry, the name of the user will show in a TextView. My other intents work just fine except this last one. For some reason this always returns a Null, when i log.d it out it will also crash the app

Note: log.d in ResultsActiivity returns name

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    EditText enter_name = findViewById(R.id.enter_name);
    Button btn_start = findViewById(R.id.btn_start);

    btn_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (enter_name.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter your name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                //create new intent for Quiz Questions activity, with a "name" information
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, QuizQuestionsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", enter_name.getText().toString());
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    TextView EnterName = findViewById(R.id.EnterName);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        if(requestCode == 1)
        {
            String message = data.getStringExtra("name");
            // Log.d("Name", message);
            EnterName.setText(String.format("Want to play again %s ?", message));
        }
        else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Name returned", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**QuizQuestionsActivity**

```
public class QuizQuestionsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String enter_name;
TextView questionID, textViewProgress;
ProgressBar progressBar;
Button optionButton1, optionButton2, optionButton3;

int questionCurrent = 1;
int correctAnswers = 0;
int maxQuestions = 5;
int currentQuestionNumber = 1;

Question[] questions = new Questions().getQuestions();
Question currentQuestion = questions[currentQuestionNumber - 1];

//Sets the initial widgets on page and updates
private void setWidgets()
{
    questionID = findViewById(R.id.questionID);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    textViewProgress = findViewById(R.id.textViewProgress);
    optionButton1 = findViewById(R.id.optionButton1);
    optionButton2 = findViewById(R.id.optionButton2);
    optionButton3 = findViewById(R.id.optionButton3);
}
private void displayQuestions()
{
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    enter_name = intent.getStringExtra("name");

    progressBar.setProgress(questionCurrent);
    textViewProgress.setText(questionCurrent + "/" + progressBar.getMax());

    questionID.setText(currentQuestion.getQuestion());
    optionButton1.setText(currentQuestion.getOptionOne());
    optionButton2.setText(currentQuestion.getOptionTwo());
    optionButton3.setText(currentQuestion.getOptionThree());
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_questions);
    setWidgets(); // this will be the initial widgets
    displayQuestions(); // these will display the initial questions
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
}

// onClick for the submit button will reset colours and display new questions
public void btnSubmit(View view)
{
    resetButtonColors();
    if (currentQuestionNumber < maxQuestions) {
        currentQuestion = questions[currentQuestionNumber++];
        questionCurrent += 1;
        displayQuestions();
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(QuizQuestionsActivity.this, ResultsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", enter_name);
        intent.putExtra("score", correctAnswers);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
}

//this is the answer checker, uses switch case to compare answers, adds correct to count
public void checkAnswer(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.optionButton1:
            if (currentQuestion.getCorrectAnswer() == 1) {
                correctAnswers++;
                optionButton1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
            else {
                optionButton1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                setCorrectColor();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.optionButton2:
            if (currentQuestion.getCorrectAnswer() == 2) {
                correctAnswers++;
                optionButton2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
            else {
                optionButton2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                setCorrectColor();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.optionButton3:
            if (currentQuestion.getCorrectAnswer() == 3) {
                correctAnswers++;
                optionButton3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
            else {
                optionButton3.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                setCorrectColor();
            }
            break;
        default: break;
    }
}
//this will set the colour if the answer is correct from above
public void setCorrectColor()
{
    switch (currentQuestion.getCorrectAnswer())
    {
        case 1: optionButton1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        break;
        case 2: optionButton2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        break;
        case 3: optionButton3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        break;
        default: break;
    }
}
//this function will reset the colours to initial when new questions come
public void resetButtonColors()
{
    optionButton1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#9E9E9E"));
    optionButton2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#9E9E9E"));
    optionButton3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#9E9E9E"));
}
```

}

**Results Activity**

```
public class ResultsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView ending, finalScore;
String enter_name;

private void setWidgets()
{
    ending = findViewById(R.id.ending);
    finalScore = findViewById(R.id.finalScore);
}
private void displayData()
{
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    enter_name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    int score = intent.getIntExtra("score", 0);
    ending.setText("Congratulations " + enter_name);
    finalScore.setText(score + " / 5");
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);
    setWidgets();
    displayData();
}
//will create a intent to the original page to start new quiz
public void newQuiz(View view)
{
    // Log.d("Name", enter_name);
    Intent intent2 = new Intent();
    String message = enter_name;
    intent2.putExtra("name", message);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent2);
    finish();
}
//automatically closes the application
public void finish(View view)
{
    this.finishAffinity();
}
```

Let me know what you thiink is wrong with it. In the main activity page i have noticed that

```
data.getExtras().getString()
```

does not work as well

When i log it out

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent {  }} to activity {com.example.quizapplication/com.example.quizapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
```

Comment: Your intent is to QuizQuestionsActivity. For the crash we need to see a log, but maybe that's because your intent is null in ResultsActivity - add a null check to the intent.

Comment: The first function there is to pass the name to the Quiz Questions activity, mean the OnActivityResult in the Main Activity and the newQuiz() function in the Results Activity. I have now attached the log message

Comment: Please also post the QuizQuestionsActivity code

Comment: I just included QuizQuestionsActivity @UrbanR

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your question. In general, you should [edit] the question to *clarify* it, but not to include an answer within it. You should create your own answer with the code/solution you used to solve your problem, and then accept it (the system may require a 48-hour delay before doing so). When you've solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer).

Comment: In your QuizQuestionsActivity you forgot to put extra to your intent in your onActivityResult method. There you should add the enter_name to the intent.

Answer (score 0):

**To retrieve value from intent you can use:**

```
    getIntent().getStringExtra(NAME_OF_EXTRA_STRING);
```